# Why am I getting an "Invalid command 'ProxyPass'" error when I start my Apache 2.2 server?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, proxypass

I'm having trouble getting Proxying working in Apache 2.2

When I try to start it, I get an `Invalid command 'ProxyPass'` error. that would be indicative of `proxy_http_module` not being loaded. However when I look at the debug, it seems to be there. e.g.,

```
E:\Apache\bin>httpd -e debug
[Fri Aug 21 15:48:55 2015] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module actions_module
...
[Fri Aug 21 15:48:55 2015] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_ajp_module
[Fri Aug 21 15:48:55 2015] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module proxy_http_module   <-----
[Fri Aug 21 15:48:55 2015] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module setenvif_module
....
[Fri Aug 21 15:48:55 2015] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module jk_module
[Fri Aug 21 15:48:55 2015] [notice] Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API
Syntax error on line 84 of E:/Apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included
in the server configuration
```

So it looks to me that proxy_http_module is loading. I don't understand why it doesn't know what ProxyPass is.

I've certainly turned it on in my `httpd.conf` file

```
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so     # <--------------
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Note: I am trying to do this through an SSL connection so I'm loading `httpd-ssl.conf` as well later on in my `httpd.conf` file

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Then in `httpd-ssl.conf` I've set up a VirtualHost entry

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "E:/Apache/htdocs"
### dummy IP
    ServerName 127.12.34.56:443
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    ErrorLog "E:/Apache/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "E:/Apache/logs/access.log"

    #ProxyRequests Off
### It chokes on the following entry
    ProxyPass / http://myfirewalledserver:80/
    #ProxyPassReverse / http://myfirewalledserver:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

What have I missed here?

Comment: *proxy_http* module requires *proxy*, and *ProxyPass* directive is defined in the latter. Just to be sure: is it also loaded?

Comment: much better... thank  you... if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it post haste.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

*proxy_http* module requires *proxy*, and *ProxyPass* directive is defined in the latter.

Make sure it's also loaded.

Thanks to  Milind Singh

Load the module by running

```
Run sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Comment: Run `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`